# Show that the determinant of any outer product is 0

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I want to show that for any two vectors $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and given $M = ab^T$, $\det(M) = 0$. I've come up with the following proof, but I'm not sure if it's sufficient; could someone double-check it?

Given $M = ab^T$, the system of equations $Mx = 0$ is equivalent to $ab^Tx = a(b \cdot x) = 0$. Then there exists a nonzero vector $x$ that is orthogonal to $b$, and so $a(b \cdot x) = a \times 0 = 0$. The existence of a nonzero $x$ such that $Mx = 0$ implies that $M$ is singular, and therefore $\det(M) = 0$.

Is this proof correct? More interestingly, is there a much simpler proof that I'm missing?

Comment: This proof is perfectly correct.

Comment: Well, except for $n = 1$.

Comment: @MichaelBiro a technicality, but a good point, I hadn't considered that. Do determinants even exist in $\mathbb{R}^1$?

Comment: @Bluefire Yup, but they aren't very interesting. For a real number $a$, $\text{det}(a) = a$.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the rank of $ab^T$ is $\leq 1$.

Comment: $n=0$ is also a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether it is a simpler proof - it's based on the property that projection matrices have zero determinant - and it can be presented in the following way:

$\text{det}(M)=\text{det}(M^T)$

Then

$\text{det}(M)\text{det}(M)=\text{det}(MM^T)=\text{det}(ab^Tba^T)=b^Tb(\text{det}(aa^T))$,

but $P=aa^T$ is known as a  projection matrix (scaled if $\Vert a \Vert \neq 1$, if $\Vert a \Vert = 1$ we have $P=P^2$) onto $a$ line   so $\text{det}(aa^T)=0 $,

hence $\text{det}(M)=0$.

Comment: How do you know $\det(aa^T)=0$ please? I can't find on [wiki for projection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix). It's been awhile since I've done linear algebra, but I recall using this in numerical analysis/scientific computing and statistics.

Comment: @BCLC The other way for explaining why $aa^T$ has determinant $0$ is to notice that for non-zero vectors $a$ rank of $aa^T$ must be $1$  Indeed take any vector $v$ and transform it with $aa^T$ - we have $aa^Tv= a(a^Tv)$ where dot product $a^Tv$ is just a scalar , say k, henceforth any result of this transformation must be of the form $ka$. If the matrix has no full rank ( for $n>1$) then determinant must be $0$.

Comment: thanks. I guess I'll analyse later.

Comment: @BCLC If a is a vector then $aa^T$ has columns linearly dependent henceforth the determinant is equal zero - it's easy to check it when we present $a^T$ as $[ a_1 \ \  a_2 \dots a_n]$,  $( a_i) $ are scalars, and we do described multiplication $aa^T$. Of course formally we should add that dimension of vector $n>1$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your proof is right. A more elementary one in my opinion would be the observation that the rows of matrix $M$ are same up to a constant. Observe that first row is $b$ scaled by $a_1$ (first entry of $a$), and second row is $b$ scaled by $a_2$ and so on. Then you can do row-elimination to create zero-rows, which then results in a zero-determinant. Yet another one is the observation that $0$ is a eigenvalue of $M$. Now, you can use the more heavy result that determinant is a product of eigenvalues.

Comment: Even simpler is to note that each column of $M$ is a scalar multiple of $a$, so the columns are obviously linearly dependent.

Comment: @amd isn't both same. I looked at rows and you looked at columns

Comment: Yes, and then one can stop right there because linearly dependent rows/columns $\iff$ zero determinant is a fundamental property of determinants.